# Convert "Jul 01, 2020" to yyyymmdd(20200701) in aws athena

Tags: hive, amazon-athena

I have aws athena table and table one column  data having like "Jul 01, 2020" , so i want to convert to yyyymmdd format. Please suggest the solution.

-- > Convert "Jul 01, 2020" to yyyymmdd(20200701) in aws athena

Thanks,
Prasad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `date_format`:

```
select date_format(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(col_name, 'MMM dd, yyyy')),
                   'yyyyMMdd') as formatted
from table;
```